# How to run eclipse on AWS

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I have successfuly run rStudio on Amazon Web Services and it is extremely useful.
I want to run eclipse on AWS as well. When I type this in to google most tutorials are about the eclipse plugin. That's not what I want. I want to run eclipse on AWS.

I tried setting up an instance on EC2 which allowed me to run windows server 2012 but I couldn't install anything because of various internet explorer configuration issues and anyway I hat windows. I also tried a remote linux installation but its not really what I want. I want to run eclipse so that I can access it from a public DNS in the same way that I have managed to do with rStudio. Is this possible. Are there other (even non-AWS) ways?

Comment: Have you looked at Amazon Worspaces? https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/

Comment: In the end I used eclipse Che hosted on cloudenvy which was exactly what I wanted (and totally free :)) http://www.eclipse.org/che/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that by "AWS" you are actually referring to Amazon EC2 virtual machines.

Installing software on an Amazon EC2 instance is no different to installing on any other computer -- it's the same copy of Microsoft Windows you would use elsewhere.

The difficulties you mention of running Internet Explorer on Windows 2012 is entirely part of Microsoft's (rather strange) security settings that discourage using Internet Explorer as a system administrator, in order to combat security weaknesses that people try to exploit. Windows 2012 will no longer be supported by Microsoft in 2018.

I recommend using **Windows 2016**, which does not seem to impose such restrictions. It's also a newer, supported operating system that matches Windows 10.

Then, just install the software as normal and things will work a lot better for you.

**Update:**

You're right -- IE has problems on Windows 2016 but they are different to what is happening on Windows 2012 (last time I looked).

To get around the silly Microsoft IE security:

- Run **Server Manager**
- Go to **Local Server**
- Click **IE Enhanced Security Configuration** ("On")
- Turn both settings **off**

Internet Explorer then works and you can install Eclipse.

Comment: I'm afraid the Free Tier Windows 2016 has the same restrictions. Having spent most of the morning dealing with Microsoft settings I now remember why I bought a mac. Is there an alternative...Maybe an eclipse cloud IDE?

Comment: Updated my answer.